# Can't connect to memcached

Tags: centos, memcached, memcache

We currently have memcached running on CentOS.

None of our PHP applications can connect, have tried multiple applications trying to establish access.

The most informative PHP error we get is:

> "Memcache::get()
>   [function.Memcache-get]: Server
>   127.0.0.1 (tcp 11211) failed with: Permission denied (13) in /var/www/.."

**memcached *1.4.5***

**PECL *2.25***

We can telnet and it works.

IP tables is full access from lo to lo.

We've tried this on two different servers with both compiled version and the rpm in CentOS 5.5 and get the same result.

Is there anything fairly obvious that we are missing?

Answer (score 3):

is selinux on?

```
getenforce
```

You can disable it for testing via

```
setenforce 0
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. That turned out to be what it was.

Comment: This is a horrible answer. See this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29851476/650206) for a proper way to fix this without sacrificing security. Although for this, the command would be: `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_memcache 1`